# Regular expression with preg_match_all

Tags: php

i got a problem occuring when using regular expressions:

```
php> $html = "<html><head><body><h1>hello world</h1><img src=\"data:rawIMGdata\" /><p/><img src=\"sdfsdf.jpg\" title=\"pic1\" /><p/><div class=\"myclass\"><img src=\"data:imageData\" /></div><img alt=\"bla\" src=\"bla.jpg\" title=\"bla\" /></body></html>";
php> $pat = '/<img.*src="(data:.*)"/m';
php> preg_match_all($pat, $html, $matching);
php> var_dump($matching);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(169) "<img src="data:rawIMGdata" /><p/><img src="sdfsdf.jpg" title="pic1" /><p/><div class="myclass"><img src="data:imageData" /></div><img alt="bla" src="bla.jpg" title="bla""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "data:imageData" /></div><img alt="bla" src="bla.jpg" title="bla"
  }  
}
```

My expected output would be just an occurence of "data:imageData" in the second array and moreover there should be two matches ("data:rawIMGdata")

Did i define my regex a wrong way?

Regards,
Broncko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using DOM Document for parsing HTML, although if this example is a complex as it is going to get then you can probably get away with regex; DOM Document will always be more robust though.

Try this:

```
/<img.*?src="(data:[^"]*)"/m
```

The ? sets the * to be non-greedy (so it will get the minimum match, by default it grabs as much as it can)

And rather than match anything, you can match anything that isn't a " with [^"].

The .* before was being greedy and matching up to the " in another element

Comment: That works great for me! Guess i have to get a bit deeper into regex. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You're basically telling PCRE to grab too much information. Regular expression matching operators will match as much as possible, which is why you're getting so much extra stuff in your matches. Firstly, switch to using the non-greedy variants for matching the initial whitespace, and or matching the contents of the element. Secondly, introduce a proper delimiter to match the end of the attribute's contents. Here's the pattern you ought to be using:

```
$pat = '/<img.*?src="(data:[^"]*)"/m';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to parse valid (almost valid) HTML you may try using [tools just for parsing XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) like [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) which allows you to browse trough XML quite effectively.

RegExp will definitely do the job, but once you swap `'` for `"` or html changes from `<img src="">` to `<img class="" src="">` you may have an issue.

XML parsing utils also usually take care about escaping and "unescaping" arguments, handles duplicate arguments.

For example use [`DOMxPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) (here's [[tutorial]](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->Load('book.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//img';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if( !$entry->hasElement('src')){
        continue;
    }

    $src = $entry->getAttribute( 'src');

    if( strncmp( $src, 'data:', 5) != 0){
       continue;
    }

    $content = substr( $src, 5);

    // Do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Simple: the HTML might not be parseable by an XML parser. OP's example might be, but that's no guarantee that everything they might be putting through the code will be.

Comment: `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` does a pretty reasonable job of parsing janky markup, but it's far from perfect. Browser parsers tend to take a more dismal approach to parsing than `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` does and will attempt to parse anything, no matter how bad. `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` does a reasonable job, all things considered, but it doesn't try quite as hard.

Also, You could eliminate a lot of your logic by expanding on your XPath expression as follows:

     //img[starts-with(@src, "data:")]/@src

That will evaluate to some `DOMAttr` objects and you can grab their `value` attributes.

Comment: @KeithGaughan I've spent 2 years in my previous job extracting data from various sites and some of them had html so terrible that it gave me and headache (so I've written enormous amount of regexps in that job). I understand and agree that sometimes regex is best (or only) solution how to get required data without great deal of effort but I also believe that you **should** use xml parser when it's possible (without negative side effects)  and you **should** point every programmer to different options (at least as a study material).

Comment: I actually agree and use things like BeautifulSoup and DOMDocument::loadHTML() myself, did my fair share of content scraping in the distant past, however we don't know all the OP's use cases and they were asking specifically about a regex problem. The only real problem I have with your answer is that it wasn't couched in terms of being a potentially more robust solution while also explaining what was wrong with their regex.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely better!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 'lazy' expression -

```
$pat = '/<img(.*?)src="(data:.*)"/m';
```

More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html